# Terminal with messed up characters

Tags: gnome-terminal

My terminal is displaying messed up characters. I already restarted my computer, but it isn't fixed. Here's a sample of the output from `pstree`. Any idea of why this happens?

[image]

Comment: Try this http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28153

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure local`